# How can I push a new screen after the last item is viewed in CarouselView?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a `CarouselView` that is bound an object model. When the user has **finished** paging through all the objects (i.e. is "about to swipe past the last view") I'd like to jump to another screen by using `Navigation.PushAsync()`. How can I do this?

I have thought about having a 'dummy object' in the underlying collection and using `CurrentItemChanged` to check if my 'special last object' is displayed, then push the finish page - but this seems very messy.

Comment: I think what you thought is right that check if the current item is the last object and then decide to whether to push or not.

Comment: But I need ti display the last item THEN show the next screen when the user swipes past the last one...

Comment: The more I think about this the more I think I need a dummy object. Unless there is a "Scrolled Past Last Card" event or way to determine it ...

Comment: You want to push to a new screen when user swipe at the last item?

Comment: Hi - when the user swipes past the last item

Comment: I would agree with you to add a 'dummy object' at the last index of itemSoure and use CurrentItemChanged to detect if you have reached the last item.